# the MainActivity.kt doesn't recognize the buttons that exists in activity_main.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I saw I lot of videos says that the Kotlin can recognize the buttons (views) automatically in MainActivity.kt I try this but it doesn't work for me in android studio 4.1 when I'm using the usual code with :

> var button_name = findViewById(R.id.buttonName)

it works fine but when I'm using the code directly like this :

> buttonName.setonclicklistiner{}

the IDE doesn't recognize the button

PS : this the imports in the mainactivity

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: you just compile and build it will work

Comment: You need to add android ktx extensions to your build files for this to work.

Comment: don't forget to add    these to extensions in your gradle.  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Comment: If you post images of code or error messages, please also copy/paste or type the actual code/message directly into the post. While images and screenshots can be helpful for providing context, the post should still be clear and useful without them. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)—the same reasoning applies to error messages as well.  Posts in which essential text is only included in images are likely to be closed for not having enough details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the following , mostly IDE will auto-import when you compile

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```